# How to implement scroll feature using iscroll javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have copied the javascript of iscroll-lite from [here](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/master/build/iscroll-lite.js)

**html code**

```
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper-container" class="wrapper-container">
    <div id="header" class="header">
    <div id="header_title" class="header_title"> </div>
    <div id="abc" class="abc"><img src="img/abc.png""/>                     </div>
</div>
<div id="images" class="images"><img  name="slide" src="img/abc.png" width=100%; />
</div>
<div id="description"  class="description">
<div id="title" class="title">
    <h1><strong></strong></h1>
</div>
<div id="desc" class="desc">
</div>
</div>  

<div id="footer" style="background-image:url(img/bar.png);" class="footer">
<div id="footer_text" class="footer_text">footer_text</div>
<div id="image" class="image noSelect"><img src="img/info.png" onclick="info()"/></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**The content of desc tag is going to overflow**

**CSS**

```
.wrapper
{
    position: absolute; width:auto; margin:0 auto; height:100%; overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper_other
{
     width:auto; margin:0 auto; height:100%; overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper_container
{
    width:100%;  margin:0 auto; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}
.header
{
    float:left; height:100%;  min-height:100%; margin:0%; width:96%; padding:3% 2% 0;
}
.header_title
{
     float:left; padding:0%; margin:0%;  height:100%; min-height:100%; font-size:22px; color: #FFFFFF; text-align:center; font-weight: bold; width:80%; 
}

.images
{
    position:relative; width:100%;
}
.description
{
     float:left; width:100%; overflow:auto;  height:100%; 

}
.title
{
    width:85%; font-weight:bold; float:left; font-size:20px; margin-top:3%; margin-bottom:2%; margin-left:5%; color:#FFFFFF; 
}
.desc
{
      width:90%; font-size:15px; margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%; float:left; color: #FFFFFF; overflow:auto; text-align:justify; line-height:18px; padding:0px 0px 40px 0px; 
}
.desc p
{
      margin-top:0; 
}
.footer
{
     width:100%;  position:absolute; bottom:0; font-size:11px; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; height:30px;
}
.footer_text
{
    text-indent:1%; float:left; text-align:center;  width:75%;  margin-top:2%;
}
.info
{
    width:25%; float:right; padding-top:1%;
}
```

**USING iscroll**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="iscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf=8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script> 


var myScroll;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function scroll() 
{
myScroll = new IScroll('.wrapper', { scrollX:false , scrollY:true});
}
----
----
function onDeviceReady() 
{   
    scroll();
    ----
    ----
```

On scrolling,I just get the following

```
W/webview(3101): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

**PROBLEM:**

**It is is not scrolling.If at all it does after great effort on it but,it scrolls only once.I go back to the main page and return it does not scroll at all.**

I have tried implementing the iscroll java script for my application as a remedial process for the CSS **position:fixed** that does not work in android 2 and 3 versions using **cordova 2.1.0**

Please,Guide me!!

Comment: Your code above contains syntax errors, for example <img src="img/abc.png""/> is invalid HTML because of the double quote, and document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); will result in a JS error because the onDeviceReady() function has not been defined yet. Maybe consider posting a debugged, working version of your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and it will be easier to see where the problem is and for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980231/how-to-use-iscroll-javascript-in-phone-gap).

The concept was implementing with the tags such as `<ul>` and `<li>` within the `<wrapper>` and `<scroller>` div.

Excellent answer!