# What is the default behavior of iscroll.

Tags: javascript, iscroll

I am using iscroll 4 and initiate an iscroll
    var test = new iScroll('iscroll-wrapper-grid');
    http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4
and I am getting a strange behavior the scrollable div does been scrolled indeed but 
when my finger stops touching the scrollable area it gets back to its initial position. 
Is this the default behavior or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing it wrong. Since you did not post what you had try I am not able to exactly tell what could be the cause. But I hope this post will help you.
[how to use iscroll javascript in phone gap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980231/how-to-use-iscroll-javascript-in-phone-gap/17114527#17114527)

If that post failed to meet your answer please get back to me with what you had try.

Answer (score 0):

`#wrapper { position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; }`

I just met this problem and fixed it, make sure your wrapper div's position is absolute or fixed, and top and bottom are defined.