# focus on text area while typing text page jumps with phonegap in android 2.3.4

Tags: android, jquery, iscroll

i had implemented iscroll on phonegap application,it works pretty good on iOS 5,6 but it behaving weired on android 2.3.4.Main issue is on text area focus keypad is up for input while typing the text the page makes jumping up and down.**[check this](http://code.google.com/p/iscroll-js/issues/detail?id=38)**..Give me a solution to replicate this issue...

Comment: Check the following post which explains your scenario

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980231/how-to-use-iscroll-javascript-in-phone-gap