# Iscroll 4 - How to scroll to a particular element based on some id?

Tags: iscroll, iscroll4

I am using `iScroll Lite base on iScroll v4.1.6` in my project and this scrolling is working perfectly fine. My structure for iscroll is given below:

```
<article id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="contentScroller">
           <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <TBODY>
                        <tr class="datatable_row" id="1">
                              <td width="10%">13/02/2013</td>
                     <td class="narration" width="28%">Chq paid</td>
                </tr>
                        <tr class="datatable_row" id="2">
                               <td>16/02/2013</td>
                    <td class="narration">Chq paid</td>
                 </tr>
                   </TBODY>
          </table>
    </div>
</article>
```

And the Javascript code for Iscroll apply is given below:

```
var scrollContent;

function loaded() {
    scrollContent = new iScroll('contentWrapper');

}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

Now you can see that there are so many `<tr>` elements in my table which are coming dynamically having an id. Now suppose I want to scroll to `<tr>` which has id 7 . How can I do this?

I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
scrollContent.scrollToElement("#7", "1s");
```

Giving error in console, which is:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute query: '#7' is not a valid selector.`

Please let me know how to scroll to a particular id using Iscroll.

Comment: I am not quite sure that you can use number as an ID. You could have try ID as "tr_1", "tr_2", "tr_3", "tr_4" ...  And your iScroll instance is "scrollContent" not "myScroll", and the time you have to pass in integer format if I am not mistaken. I used this "scrollToElement" a lot but all the time I use integer for timestamp and never use number for DOM id. But I never end up in any issue so far

Comment: @FaizulHasan I also tried with ID as you said like "tr_1", "tr_2" but no use of it. Scroll is not happening to that perticular ID. If any sample you have , can you share with me.

Comment: check by changing the default option "checkDOMChanges" to true

Comment: I think you might have to refer http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 for further information. You use lite version but I use normal version. Please refer "KNOWN ISSUES AND FUTURE DEVELOPMENT" under "ISCROLL LITE EDITION". I think that could be reason.

Comment: I am not quite sure what messed up here. But I have to make sure your iScroll is working with your current implementation( I am not asking about the scrollToElement). Please make sure whether it is working or not. Because I found incompatible DOM structure for iScroll. Please refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980231/how-to-use-iscroll-javascript-in-phone-gap/17114527#17114527